# How to keep track of files in this case ? C#

Tags: c#, .net

I wanna do a software, but I really don't know how to keep track of this things.

The idea is this:

1. I select a folder
2. Give a maximum of lines (eg 300000)
3. Give a lines/packet (eg 8000)

The software has to do this. Go to each file in folder (I managed to get it done until here, lol) open each file and save his lines. If file1.txt has for eg 3000 lines, save them into a file, go to next file, if the second file has 2000 lines, save that too, until I have 8000 lines into a package. Once 8000 lines are found, save the file like "packet1.txt", go to next files, and so on ... UNTIL all the lines have reached the maximum number of lines (300 000) in this case.

This is the code:

```
if (!path(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath))
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a folder!");
else if ((textBox1.Text != "") && (textBox2.Text != "") && (textBox4.Text!=""))
{
    folder = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    maxlinks = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    packetlink = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    //  apikey = textBox4.Text;
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
    {

    }
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Please check your input!");
```

PS: The path function only checks if the directory is selected.

Can somebody give some ideas?

Comment: Do you know how to read the lines from a single file, and how to write lines to a new file? If so, its just a matter of looping this action over every file you've found (you said you can find files fine) and keeping track of how many lines you've written to the current package so you know when to switch.

Comment: If you can post the code you've already written perhaps we can help guide you.

Comment: lol :) no. I am making a software for somebody, to make a big story short, I wrote the description that way. The ideea is that this is a part of it. Lines=links. Actually it's a software that uses an API, and creates links and submits them for indexing them at a website.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx

so

```
if (!path(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath))
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a folder!");
else if ((textBox1.Text != "") && (textBox2.Text != "") && (textBox4.Text!=""))
{
    folder = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    maxlinks = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    packetlink = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    //  apikey = textBox4.Text;
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file = 
           new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
        while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null && counter < 30000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (line);
            counter++;
        }

        file.Close();
    }

}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please check your input!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is reading from a file, I already know that. I posted this here because I thought somebody could right the pseudocode for what I need, or something like that :)